# Explicit __init__ python

Tags: python-3.x, constructor

```
class A(object):
    __init__ = None

def A__init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

A.__init__ = A__init__
```

I am new to python so i want to ask for the differences between the constructor above and the below one.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Comment: there is none, effectively. you've arrived at the same destination taking a slightly different and unusual path.

Comment: There is no difference. Your first approach is just not standard, and doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There are some inspectional differences. E.g. `A.__init__.__name__` will be different in the two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in terms of usage, there will be no clear differences. Notice, however, that the naming does change, as,

```
>>>print(A.__init__.__name__)
```

Outputs `__init__` in the normal case, but `A__init__` in the case where you bind a function as the `__init__` method for `A`.

Beyond this, if `A` ever enters into a class hierarchy, you can also not rely on `super()` to figure out the MRO for you, and will have to use something along the lines of `super(type(self), self)` for this to work. Monkey-patching `__init__` is just a little odd, eh.

Comment: You shouldn't do this: `super(type(self), self)`, instead, you have to hard-code the class, i.e. `super(A, self)`.